# Accessing elements inside iframe with another DOM

Tags: iframe, protractor, ui-automation

I was able to access the iframe, but I can't access locators inside it. I noticed that the iframe actually has a whole page inside it. Any thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.switchTo().frame($('.full-iframe').getWebElement());
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.